# Java 7 unable to use ECC keys

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

Whether using `keytool` or plain Java code, creating signatures using elliptic curves doesn't work on Java `1.7.0_85` for me out-of-the-box.

For example - using `keytool` to generate a new EC key on NIST P-256 curve:

```
keytool -v -genkeypair -alias my_key -keyalg EC -keysize 256 -keystore test.jks
```

throws the following exception:

```
keytool error: java.security.SignatureException: Could not sign data
java.security.SignatureException: Could not sign data
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineSign(ECDSASignature.java:297)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1205)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:578)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.sign(X509CertImpl.java:524)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.sign(X509CertImpl.java:474)
    at sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen.getSelfCertificate(CertAndKeyGen.java:269)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doGenKeyPair(KeyTool.java:1558)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:969)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.KeyException
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.signDigest(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineSign(ECDSASignature.java:293)
    ... 9 more
```

As this is a quite low-level exception, the same exception is thrown wherever I want to use EC signature in my Java code.

I checked whether my `java.security` file has the `SunEC` provider installed, but everything looks fine:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
```

and also the `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/` contains the `sunec.jar`.
Also the `US_export_policy.jar` and `local_policy.jar` are in the `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder.

Any ideas what might be the cause? ECC is supposed to work with Java 7.

**EDIT**: Here's also the Java code for generating the same exception as I get with `keytool` - I use slightly different scenario - converted PKCS12 certificate with EC P-256 key into JKS keystore. The exception is thrown when `sign()` method is called at the last line.

```
KeyStore kst = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
kst.load(new FileInputStream("kst.jks"), "******".toCharArray());

Key k = kst.getKey("my_key", "******".toCharArray());
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
sig.initSign((PrivateKey)k);
sig.update("test".getBytes());
System.out.println(bytesToHex(sig.sign()));
```

Comment: The provider is obviously loaded & used if I look at the exception; it contains sun.security.ec.* classes. Is there any deeper exception? Do you have code for generating the exception (i.e. signature generation)? Although I don't think it *should* work, could you try `ecdsa ` as `keyalg` in the `keytool` command?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I was digging deeper and found out the exception originates from the native code - however any information about the native error code is not propagated to the Java level, so all I get is just the `KeyException`. If I use `ecdsa` as `keyalg` I get `Cannot derive signature algorithm` exception.

Comment: Could you print out `k.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: `sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl`. I found out that the whole problem seems to be connected solely with the OpenJDK (both 7 and 8) - when I use Oracle JRE 8, ECC works properly.

Comment: Hmm sound like a bug to me in that case...

Comment: It probably is, when I replaced the `libsunec.so` with the one from the Oracle JDK it works correctly again. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome. If you create a bug report at Oracle I'm happy to vote for it (if it isn't hidden, crypto related bugs usually are, at least initiailly).